# Fill ellipse in Silverlight (in the .cs file)

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to fill an ellipse with a linear gradient variable in Silverlight(in the .cs file). Here is what I have tried...

```
        newEllipse.Fill = ballBG;
```

However, this removes the fill that is already on the ellipse. I also tried...

```
        newEllipse.Background = ballBG;
```

However, it comes up with this error...'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse' does not contain a definition for 'Background' and no extension method 'Background' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: "However, this removes the fill that is already on the ellipse. " What behavior do you expect?

Comment: There is no `Background` property on `Ellipse`. Also, what type is `ballBG`?

Comment: LinearGradientBrush ballBG = new LinearGradientBrush();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having a SolidColorBrush:

```
Ellipse redEllipse = new Ellipse();
redEllipse.Height = 100;
redEllipse.Width = 300;           
SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;
SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
redEllipse.StrokeThickness = 4;
redEllipse.Stroke = blackBrush;

redEllipse.Fill = redBrush;
```

**UPDATE**
For your LinearGradientBrush I found this:

```
LinearGradientBrush myBrush=new LinearGradientBrush ();

myBrush.SetValue(LinearGradientBrush.StartPointProperty, ("0,0"));
myBrush.GradientStops(1).Offset = 0.5;

myBrush.SetValue(LinearGradientBrush.EndPointProperty, ("1,1"));
myBrush.GradientStops(0).Color = Colors.Red;

myBrush.GradientStops(1).Color = Colors.Green;

newEllipse.Fill = myBrush;
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, anyway to do the same with a LinearGradientBrush?